# Dense subset in $\mathbb R^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega = [-1,1]\times[-1,1] \subset \mathbb R^{2}$ & $\lambda \gt 0$ be a constant.Let $L_{n}$ & $K_{n}$ be the lines with slope $\lambda$ passing through the points (sin $n$ ,$-1$) & ($-1$,cos $n$) respectively. Furthermore, $A = \bigcup_{n} (L_{n} \bigcap \Omega)$ & $B= \bigcup_{n} (K_{n} \bigcap \Omega) $. Show that $\overline {A \bigcup B} = \Omega $.

**My thoughts**: Intuitively, the picture is clear. Here we have to use the facts that sin $n$ & cos $n$ are dense in $[-1,1]$. & clearly any straight line within the $\Omega$ will have to intersect lower side OR the left-most side of $\Omega$ & using the density of sin $n$ & cos $n$ in $[-1,1]$ we will have elements from A & B.

But, I am stuck at writing the proof rigorously!! So, can anyone please provide a rigorous proof??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $p=\langle a,b\rangle\in\Omega$. Let $L$ be the line of slope $\lambda$ through $\langle-1,-1\rangle$; its equation is $y=\lambda x+\lambda-1$. For convenience let $f(x)=\lambda x+\lambda-1$. If $b\le f(a)$, $p$ lies on or below $L$. Let $L(p)$ be the line of slope $\lambda$ through $p$; it intersects the bottom edge of $\Omega$ at a point $\langle x_p,-1\rangle$. You can calculate $x_p$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. For any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n$ such that $|x_p-\sin n|<\epsilon$. Show that this implies that there is a point on $L_n$ within $\epsilon$ of $p$.

If $b>f(a)$, $L(p)$ intersects the lefthand edge of $\Omega$, and you do the same thing with the other set of lines.